# index out of bounds error in nested loop

Tags: dafny

Can someone tell me why this code generates an "index out of bounds" error on `input[i*cols + j]`?

```
method foo(input: array<int>, rows:int, cols:int)
requires input != null 
requires rows > 0 && cols > 0
requires rows * cols == input.Length
{
   var i := 0;
   while i < rows
   {
     var j := 0;
     while j < cols
     {
       var s := input[i*cols + j];
       j := j + 1;
     }
     i := i + 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is error free, but Dafny has trouble proving it.

In order to show that the index is in bounds, Dafny needs to prove:

```
i*cols + j < rows * cols
```

given `i < rows` and `j < cols` (and given a few other facts).

This formula is nonlinear (meaning that it contains a multiplication of two variables). In general, such formulas do not lie in decidable fragments of logic, and in practice, this means that the solver underlying Dafny has trouble reasoning about them effectively.

Now, in fact, this formula is true. It's just that the solver is having trouble seeing why. We can help it out by breaking down the proof into smaller steps.

Here is a complete version of your program that verifies.

```
lemma lemma_mul_le(x: int, y: int, z: int)
  requires 0 <= z
  requires x <= y
  ensures x * z <= y * z
{}

method foo(input: array<int>, rows:int, cols:int)
  requires input != null 
  requires rows > 0 && cols > 0
  requires rows * cols == input.Length
{
   var i := 0;
   while i < rows
   {
     var j := 0;
     while j < cols
     {
       lemma_mul_le(i, rows-1, cols);
       var s := input[i*cols + j];
       j := j + 1;
     }
     i := i + 1;
   }
}
```

I have introduced a lemma, which says that for any `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `0 <= z` and `x <= y` then `x * z <= y * z`. Dafny is able to prove this without any further help. (We call this "proof by open-close brace"!)

I then call the lemma in the body of `foo` with some particular values for `x`, `y`, and `z`. I chose these values by working through the proof that the index is in bounds by hand.

Dafny is able to verify both that the lemma is true and that, given the lemma, the access is in bounds. This results in a program with no errors. Hooray!

---

One may wonder: how can it be that Dafny is able to prove the lemma without any help, and yet it cannot prove the original program?

This is a reasonable thing to wonder. Such wonders are the price one pays for automated verification. In general, there may be multiple equivalent ways of formulating a logical query that get wildly different performance from the solver. There is an art to coaxing the solver to do your bidding.

In the specific case of this program, one way to think about it is in terms of the query Dafny will send to the solver. In order to verify `foo`, Dafny will send a queries to the solver that have "in scope" all relevant variables and facts. This can lead the solver to get side-tracked or otherwise confused when asked to prove a seemingly simple nonlinear arithmetic query. By factoring the offending formula into a lemma, we're essentially forcing the solver to focus on the hard part, by eliminating all the irrelevant facts that were in scope when reasoning about `foo`. In this case, it turns out that this was enough to get the proof to go through. In more difficult cases, other tricks might be required.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So in general is there a way to know where the solver gets stuck (and thus provide the appropriate lemmas)? How would this compare to using something like coq, where at least we know the current state of the solver?

Comment: Dafny will generally tell you which assertion or proof obligation it couldn't finish. But it doesn't typically give you much more information than that. One trick you can play is to use `assert`s to see whether facts you think are relevant are provable. That's how I debugged your problem: I asserted `i * cols + j < rows * cols`. Dafny was unable to prove that assert, but it was able to show that the index was in bounds *assuming* my assert was true. So I knew I was on the right track.

Comment: Comparing to Coq is tricky because there are so many dimensions to compare along. You're right that Coq rarely leaves you in a situation where you don't have enough information to figure out why something didn't work. On the other hand, the steps that Coq can make for you tend to be much smaller. Furthermore, verifying imperative programs in Coq is a relatively advanced topic, whereas it is central to Dafny.